# How do I export a jar with an sqlite database inside?

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, deployment, jar

I have a program that I want to distribute, without giving the source code or database used. It's an sqlite database, and doesn't need to be updated. I tried using eclipse fatjar and changing where to look for the jar, but when I run the program, it just creates a blank database file in the same directory as the jar. I just want one file that I can distribute.

---

From comments deemed relevant:

> ..include an XML after tested with a TXT file.

I would, but this database is 80,000 lines long, and has 4 columns. It's only going to get bigger too, with updates to the program, not during runtime.

> Put it on a server and have a web interface.

I want to avoid using any internet connection really. If someone wants to decompile the jar, whatever I don't care. I just want it to *work from double click, and no extra files laying around.*

Comment: I did something similar, but in the ending I chose to include an XML after tested with a TXT file.

Comment: @PaulVargas I would, but this database is 80,000 lines long, and has 4 columns. It's only going to get bigger too, with updates to the program, not during runtime.

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry about that, just edited it, and yeah it's just that usability and neatness is important for me in this project

Comment: No need to be sorry, but better to remember that 'more information is better than less' in these cases.  I've edited some of the comments and responses into the question. *"it's just that usability and neatness is important for me"*  Glad to see that.  I'm sick of so many amateurish installers (e.g. that need to come with a README file on how to set up the app.).

Comment: So what you're asking is how to bundle an existing database file into your jar? With both read/write access?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas *"It's an sqlite database, and **doesn't need to be updated**."*

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas what Andrew said. I just need it bundled. read-only is fine with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (deployment) ..usability and neatness is important for me

That makes me think that what is really needed for this is a cross-platform installer.  The user gets one file and double clicks it, 'follows the prompts' (if any prompts are required) & it extracts the app. ready for use.

It might create multiple files, but this will be largely invisible to the end user.  'Out of site is out of mind'.

> I want to avoid using any internet connection..

I recommend you rethink that.  What size does the app. come to when Jar'd?  A couple of megabytes?  That is nothing in this day and age of internet traffic.  That's a 2 minute YouTube.

The ratio of devices having internet connections to machines having (for example) CD/DVD drives to load software is also changing.  It is coming to a time when more machines capable of running J2SE have internet connections than have drives.  I have a desktop PC and a Netbook that can both run J2SE.  Both have an internet connection, but only the desktop PC has CD/DVD drives.

If that is the case (getting to my point) look to [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to deploy the app. and DB.  Very user friendly, with good desktop integration.

> it's about 50mb, but the problem is not all end users will have access to internet at all times. Distributing the application can be done through the internet, but I don't want to rely on it for accessing the database or loading the application all together.

That is not necessary.  JWS caches the application resources locally.  It **will** check the server for updated Jars, but can be configured to allow launch from the cached copy even if there is no internet connection at that moment.  The launch file element to configure that would look something like:

```
<update check="always" policy="prompt-run">
```

Comment: it's about 50mb, but the problem is not all end users will have access to internet at all times. distributing the application can be done through the internet, but I don't want to rely on it for accessing the database or loading the application all together.

Comment: *"not all end users will have access to internet at all times"*  Not a problem.  See the update to my answer.

Comment: hmmm. I'm not too sure still. I don't feel comfortable putting the work I've done, aka compiling the whole database, available for anyone to use if it's cached on their computer. once it's in a single jar, this is absolutely something I will use however.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of your last comment.  Is a 'desktop shortcut' something you would use as an end user?  This is all the end user might ever see of the complexity of the installation itself.  A JWS launch can be a little tricky for us (the developer) to set up right, but once it is done, it is a breeze for the end user.

Comment: would jws handle where to cache things? because it's most likely going to be used on unix platforms as well as windows. and that is what I want, maybe I understood you wrong the first time. Is there any documentation I can use to get this set up?

Comment: I've gone with this solution, just one last thing, It wants the jar and resources in the jnlp file, so how would I add the database to it?

Comment: @Mukhi  I have not any experience with deploying a DB, but have been led to believe that many DBs can deal with 'embedded data' (in a Jar) without problems.  So 'add the D/B and data to a Jar - add a ref. to the Jar in the JNLP' would be the solution there.

Comment: please refer to my new question. It's about this, and I have no idea what to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109634/jnlp-files-and-sqlite-databases

Answer (score 1):

Don't know whether you can do this with a SQLite database, but Derby supports jar: paths: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/devguide/cdevdvlp17453.html

Alternatively, extract the database from the jar to the filesystem upon launch and point there.

Comment: with derby, is it required to have a derby database, or can I leave it in sqlite format?

Comment: it would have to be a derby database, but it might be easy to port, since they both support SQL...

Comment: More specifically, use `.dump` to create a SQL file with the contents of your SQLite database. Hopefully you can just run it as a script in Derby.

Comment: how would I go about connecting to the sql file once it's been dumped?

Comment: create a Derby database and run the script using `ij`: http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/ij2.html

Comment: I've created the derby database, but for some reason random symbols appear in the queries when run through eclipse. when run through the ij tool, everything is fine. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: no, sorry. I don't have that much first-hand experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do the following:

- Package your database on the classpath.
- When the app loads, copy the database to some temporary directory (like /tmp)
- Instruct sqlite to read it from there (by setting the jdbc url)
- Add a jvm hook to delete the file when the app gets closed.

That should work like a charm.

Hint:

Use `getClass().getResourceAsStream();` to get the reference of the file on the classpath.

Comment: wouldn't doing this slow down the application a lot, especially since the database is already 40mb?

Comment: @Mukhi In that case you can consider copying it once when your app is installed or first loaded to a more convenient place there are common places for apps to store working files without messing with the user's files.

Comment: I really don't want to have to store anything on the computer. this would be perfect, if it didn't take too long.

Comment: You may install the app uncompressed (no jar, just the .class files).

Comment: I don't want to hand around class files. jars make things much neater, and easier to use.

Comment: Ok, just use a splash screen while copying the file then